# Modding a doorbell to a transceiver but need timer

Tags: switches

[image: Rough Sketch of what I'm trying to accomplish]

What is the best way to accomplish adding a switch with a 5 second 'on' feature (where the circuit is closed for 5 seconds then opens thereby turning it off)??

I was thinking of using a digital doorbell and hard wiring it between the 9VDC source and the digital transceiver, but am seeking advice on the timer (trying to create what I believe is called a monostable circuit)

Comment: The traditional (analog) approach for making a simple 9V monostable circuit would be a [555 IC](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/555_timer.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As John1024 mentioned in a comment, the standard way to implement something like this is to use a 555 circuit, something like this:

[image]

Whenever the switch is closed, it will temporarily ground pin 2 of the 555, and the output on pin 3 will go high for the delay set by the components surrounding the 555.  If the delay needs to start on a positive going pulse instead, a transistor inverter can be added to the input side of the circuit.

The values for the 452K resistor connected to pins 6 and 7, and the 10 µF capacitor connected to pin 6, have been chosen to generate a time delay of 4.97 seconds which is the closest to 5 seconds you can get with standard components.

However the timing will actually only be as good as the tolerance of the capacitor, which can usually be no better than 5%.  So that means your timeout go range from about 4.7 seconds to 5.3 seconds, depending on the components.  (Of course for a given set of components, it will always be the same.)

The values for the two timing components were chosen using this [online 555 monostable calculator](http://www.csgnetwork.com/ne555timer1calc.html).

Comment: Looking at building this for in an industrial housing. Any suggestions aside from using a breadboard and attaching to the inside of a shielded case? Thanks for the helpful reply!

Comment: You don't want to use one of those solderless breadboards where you just stick the wires in the holes (they are okay for testing the circuit out first though).  Instead us a PC board [like this](http://www.radioshack.com/multipurpose-pc-board-with-417-holes/2760150.html#start=66&q=board&sz=12).  You can mount it to the case with plastic standoffs.